# How do I invoke a command using a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to invoke the shutdown.exe executable in powershell and it is located on `C:\WINDOWS\System32\shutdown.exe`.

Since we already got the `C:\WINDOWS` in the variable `$env:windir` I want to just use it and concatenate the rest of the path into the command. I was trying this:

```
PS C:\Users\shina> .\$env:windir\System32\shutdown.exe -s
```

But I got the following error:

```
    .\$env:windir\System32\shutdown.exe: The term '.\$env:windir\System32\shutdown.exe' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Put `&` in the beginning instead of DOT followed by the full path

Comment: This should work. Remove just the `.\\` before your environment variable; it already contains the path to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
& $env:windir\System32\shutdown.exe -s
```

Or

```
. $env:windir\System32\shutdown.exe -s
```

(note the space).

---

`&` is the call operator. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2):

> Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator", lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings or script blocks.

---

`.` is the dot sourcing operator. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2):

> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current scope, overriding existing ones.

> The dot sourcing operator is followed by a space. Use the space to distinguish the dot from the dot (.) symbol that represents the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate what is the meaning of the "&" in the begiining of the command? Sorry the question, I am learning right now

Comment: @DanielOliveira Answer updated.